# How to store image in database

Tags: mysql, perl

I am trying to insert image in database. The database has a field named `images` and its type is BLOB. I am trying to insert the image, but only the first 2.2KB is stored. Even if I insert another image it stores only 2.2KB in the database.

When I try to show this image in my application it doesn't show; it's just a small icon, not the image. How can I insert the image in the right way?

```
use CGI;  
my $file = $q->param("file"); 
$file = 'C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.22/cgi-bin/images/2.jpg';
open(my $fh, $file);
my $data;
binmode($fh);
read($fh, $data, (stat($fh))[7]);
close($fh);

my $Data = {
        table    =>'student',
        data     => {    
        Image    => $fh,
        }       
};

Data::Insert($Data);

print $q->header;
print $q->start_html(
   -title => "student",
);

print $q->end_html;
```

showImage.pl

```
my $q = new CGI();
my $handle = Dbm::connection();

$id = $q->param('id_person');

$getimage = $handle->selectrow_array (<<SQLEOF); 
    SELECT Image
      FROM student  
    WHERE ID  = '$id'
SQLEOF

print "Content-Type: image/jpeg\n";
print "Content-length: \n\n";

binmode STDOUT;
print STDOUT $getimage;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You mentioned storing the file in a database, but your code sample doesn't show any database in use, only a file. You should specify your database and version, and show the code you are using for inserting and reading from the database. Sometimes it works well just to store metadata in the database, and store images on the file system instead, with names based on the unique database IDs.

Comment: Thank you! Ok i will edit my code and please take a look after that

Comment: I think we need to see how `DB::Insert()` is implemented as well.

Comment: I just includet db subs. Please take a look

Answer (score 1):

My recomendation is keep the image as base 64 encrypted to the db with the MIME type of the image. When you need it, just decrypt it by saying MIME type. This is the mostly used to upload files using ajax. So why can't we use the same way to store image directly to DB?

Just give an additional column to keep MIME type in your table and take it along with the encoded data as print it together.

From a file extension, we can identify the type of file. The MIME type for images are mainly

```
image/gif: GIF image
image/jpeg: JPEG JFIF image;
image/pjpeg: JPEG JFIF image; 
image/png: Portable Network Graphics;
image/svg+xml: SVG vector image;
image/tiff: Tag Image File Format (only for Baseline TIFF);
```

You can create a new column by giving name as `mime_typ` . Now when you enctrypt a file using base 64 encryption, keep it as a string like we store usernames and passwords in a table. Similarly add the `MIME type` to the `mime_typ` column. when you want to show the image, print the encrypted content after decoding it along with the content in the MIME type, which is stored in the same row in the `mime_typ` column. `You can search google for the way to show an image which is encrypted in base 64 encryption.`

Comment: I dont have the option MIME in database type. I am using MySQL.

Comment: Which database you are using is an important detail. In the future, please update the original question with such important details, and in this case you could also add the "MySQL" tag, so other MySQL experts could find it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the file in binary mode - i.e.

```
open(my $fh, $myfile);
my $data;
binmode($fh);
read($fh, $data, (stat($fh))[7]);
close($fh);
```

Comment: at fileSize what should i put? How is it suposed that i know the size of all images, because i can put different pictures.

Comment: There is nothing in this answer that has to do with binary mode. Also, it is poor style. Did you mean `open my $fh, "<:raw", $myfile or die "Can't open $myfile: $!"; read $fh, my $data, -s $fh;`?

Comment: And it shows me syntax error in this line :read (FILE, $data, stat(FILE)[7]); what is stat(FILE)[7] ?

Comment: it shows me this now :Can't open 1.png: No such file or directory

Comment: @AnaVani - Make sure you are either a) in the correct directory or b) use the full path for `1.png`

Comment: how to use the full path? where should i put it? i really dont have the idea , is the first time i am trying to insert an image in database.

Comment: @AnaVani you want to save the path where the image is located or the image itself ? Ed's answer is to store the image itself inside your database.

Comment: @AnaVani - put it into `$myfile` i.e. `$myfile='/a/path/to/the/file/1.png'`

Comment: @Prix - As per the title. Have not got Perl on this machine and I am a bit rusty.

Comment: @ Ed Can't open C:/wam/bin/apache/apache2.2.22/cgi-bin/images/1.png:

Comment: @AnaVani - Does the file exist? File permissions?

Comment: now doesn't show this error , but the image is not stored in database :( what may be the problem?

Comment: @Ed Heal and doesn't show me any error. It just stores the other data in database but the image not.

Comment: I was using this : but this stores image as 2.2 KB and not the real size :my $upload_filehandle = $q->upload("myfile");

my $binfile;
open ( UPLOADFILE, ">$upload_dir/$filename" ) or die "$!";

binmode(UPLOADFILE);

while ( <$upload_filehandle>)
{
$binfile .= UPLOADFILE;
print UPLOADFILE;
}

close UPLOADFILE;

open FILE, "<$upload_dir/$filename";
$file_contents = do { local $/; <FILE> };

Comment: I just edited my code , puting there even Db subs. Please i need a solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you deleted the database-insert code from the question, but I found it in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18065148/4).

The issue could be because you aren't not using bind variables, and the binary image contains an escape character which is causing a problem.

I recommend using [DBIx::Simple](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx::Simple) to help create your insert statements that will help create the bind variables for you. DBIx::Simple works with both SQL::Abstract and SQL::Interp. I find SQL::Interp more flexible.

It also appears to be a bug that you are inserting the file handle into the image field instead of the file data. Try adding `use File::Slurp` (which you may need to install), and then putting this in your `%data` hash:

```
 Image    =>  scalar read_file($file, { binmode => ':raw' });
```

Your SELECT statement is also vulnerable to a SQL injection attack because you did not validate the outside input before passing it to the database, and you did not you bind variables again. Using `DBIx::Simple`, the same code would look like this:

```
my $db = DBIx::Simple->new($handle);
$getimage = $db->iquery("SELECT Image FROM student WHERE ID  = ",\$id)->list;
```

Also, I recommend omitting the Content-Length header, or properly calculating it, rather than leaving it present in an invalid state.

Comment: just edited my code. Please take a look now. Data :: is an other file that has a sub Insert {}. Please if you can edit my code . Thank you

Comment: I think the problem is with in bind variables, but ireally dont know how to do it. Please could you help me